# react native EXPO Javascript Obfuscation

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, expo, obfuscation

I am new to react native , i used Expo C.L.I and Firebase to develop a beautiful app, i want to publish this app to the play store hence i have to secure it , i am opting for **JavaScript Obfuscation**

I have gone through several articles but most or all of then only refer to Obfuscation a react-native CLI apps .

I actually tried converting my expo to RN then tried to Obfuscation but to no avail.

How do i go about Obfuscation my expo app?

Comment: Any updates on this? Have you tried something until now?